# Conditional String.Format on integer number

Tags: c#, string, format

Wanted to check if conditional string.Format is possible in C# on the basis value of a number.

For example

for boolean data type

```
bool rvalue = false;
string s = string.Format("{0:X;0;Y}", rvalue.GetHashCode());
```

this will return Y.

Similarly, is there any possibility of writing condition inside string.Format like if `number>2 then print X else print Y`

Comment: Related: [`";"` section separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SectionSeparator). I think it just work for positive, negative and zero numbers respectively, it can't check against certain values.

Comment: why do you use `GetHashcode` on a bool? Seems to me you´re misusing a hashcode for something, just because it works. A hashcode should never be really used somewhere in your software.

Comment: @HimBromBeere True, although the algorithm is [pretty straight-forward](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,80), you should never rely on its value.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to understand what you were trying to do with that expression, but I think I got it now.

The best I can come up with now is this:

```
int number = 3;
string s = string.Format($"{(number > 2 ? "X" : "Y")}");
```

Or:

```
int number = 3;
string s = string.Format("{0:X;0;Y}", number > 2 ? 1 : 0);
```

But this would make more sense to me:

```
int number = 3;
string s = number > 2 ? "X" : "Y";
```

Comment: you can check this expression string s = string.Format("{0:X;0;Y}", rvalue.GetHashCode()); - it works

Comment: The problem is I can not use condition apart from format string

Comment: I don't understand what that means. @RanjitSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way;

```
   bool rvalue = false;
                    string s = string.Format("{0:X;0;Y}",
                    rvalue ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply build your format-string in front:

```
string format = rvalue ? "0:X" : "0:Y";
var result = myInput.Format(format);
```

Pretty clear and easy to extend when you have more complicated conditions:

```
switch (whateverCondition)
{
    case 1: format = "0:Z"; break;
    case 2: format = "0:X"; break;
    case 3: format = "0:Y"; break;
    default: format = "whatever";
}
```